# Acces events for dynamicly created objects C#

Tags: c#

I have no experience with C# and I was wondering, if I declared a list of buttons that are created on run, How do I acces to its events? For example, just change the color of one of them when clicked.
Here is how the buttons are being created:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button aux = new Button();
            Nodes.Add(aux);
            Controls.Add(aux);
            cont++;
        }
```

Comment: `aux.Click += (s, a) => { /* do what you want here */ };` ?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 2):

You can either add Code directly when you use a Lambda Function:

```cs
aux.Click += (s, a) => { /* Execute your code here */ };
```

Or you can create a function that is called by all your Buttons if you create a Method for them and add it to the aux.Cick Event.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Button aux = new Button();
    Nodes.Add(aux);
    Controls.Add(aux);
    cont++;
    aux.Click += BtnClick;
}

private void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    // Execute your code here

    // Example of changing Background Color
    (sender as Button).Background = Brushes.Green;
}
```

Comment: You can directly use `Brushes.Green` instead of `new SolidColorBrush`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button aux = new Button();
            Nodes.Add(aux);
            Controls.Add(aux);
            cont++;
            aux.Click += (sndr, args) =>
               {
                  MessageBox.Show("clicked!");
                               
               };
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xaml? if so consider :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Backgroud" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Only change the xaml.